# Photon counting circuit

Tags: comparator, counter

Hello I am a college student working on photon counting circuit using Silicon Photomultiplier(SiPM). 
**Stage 0**: Signal from SiPM
[image]
Description: This is an image captured from oscilloscope with the time resolution between the data points being 25 ns. If the SiPM is exposed to ambient light, the voltage goes up to -3V, which I want to be safe about.
**Stage 1**: Amplifier
Description: I want to invert the voltage so that the comparator will receive only positive voltage range.
*Question 1*: At this "relatively" high speed, is an opamp circuit a good option? Or will voltage regulator integrated circuit (ic) do the job?
**Stage 2**: Comparator
Description: I am trying to output 0 or 5V by comparing the input from the amplifier to a threshold voltage of 4 mV.
Attempt 1: I purchased a MAX997 and tried to compare a sinewave of 100mV amplitude, 1kHz frequency, on a breadboard with bypass capacitor of 0.1 microF, but did not show any kind of square wave I expected. 
*Question 2*: Will comparator ic MAX997 or AD8611 be an overkill for this application (i.e too short of a propagation delay, therefore too much sampling)? if not, what kind of circuit should go around the ic to make sure I get the desired output at this relatively high frequency (bypass capacitor, resistors...etc, specific type of capacitor I need to purchase)?
**Stage 3**: Counter 
Description: I am trying to use a 12 bit counter ic such as SN74LV4040A to count the number of pulses generated by the comparator and within an adjustable amount of time window (1 ms), I want to capture that number and send it via bluetooth to different devices.
*Question 3*: Can I just put the output from the comparator straight into the clock input of the aforementioned asynchronous counter? Is asynchronous counter a good choice for this application? 
*Question 4*: Is Arduino mega a good choice for a microcontroller that will be able to transfer the count data via bluetooth (will speed be an obstacle)?

Thank you for reading thus far and I appreciate any kind of response to this question. If I have a horribly wrong understanding of this topic, please let me know. I have a lot to learn. A LOT.

**Edit01** 
I believe this was too big of a question, so I want to start off with comparator. I currently have MAX997, but I fried one by connecting the shutdown pin to the ground. I thought I was following the correct procedure according to the datasheet, but something went wrong.

Can Anyone point out my mistake, if all I had was a pull up resistor of 1k at the output of the comparator, and rest was just connected to function generator and power supply?

Also I found a paper quite similar to what I am trying to do: [link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268988318_The_ArduSiPM_a_compact_trasportable_SoftwareHardware_Data_Acquisition_system_for_SiPM_detector)

**Edit02** 
Below is the schematic I could draw to the best of my ability:
[image]

Comment: This is already a huge question, suggest you get the Arduino aspect out of it to concentrate on the core EE design problems first (especially as its mere mention is a red flag to some here).  Once you have a TTL-type pulse there are many options for counting and reporting, concentrate for the moment on getting that far.  Also, you could be more specific about the typical inter-arrival times you need to be able to treat as distinct countable events

Comment: Though if you are going to have an MCU in the system, it will be easier to use an onboard timer/counter to do the counting than an external counter you have to read from in parallel, at least up to the point where you need faster logic than you contemplated using.

Comment: "exposed to ambient light" means that, if you look at this from a quantum perspective, you see a *very* high number of photons hitting the sensor within 25ns, and the -3V might be an  event where a lot of these overlay – I wouldn't necessarily call this "photon counting", more like "statistical properties of a mass phenomenon observation"

Comment: Ambient light is probably many billions of photons per second...

Comment: Can you draw a schematic of your MAX997 circuit?

Comment: Does anyone know if the comparator part and the counter part can be done with a single microcontroller? If so, what kind of microcontroller? Arduino Due?

Answer (score 1):

1) You don't need an inverter. AC couple the input to the comparator, and set the detection levels below the new reference point. However, since you do need some gain to get your signal amplitude up, an op amp (quite high speed) is indicated, and you should be aware that you can typically configure an op amp as an inverting or non-inverting amplifier, so you get inverting for free. However, this will depend to some degree on exactly what your PM device output looks like. A voltage regulator is, well, so far off as a consideration that you need to talk to somebody about why you think it MIGHT be appropriate.

2) A 997 is just about right, since it looks like your pulse width is on the order of 50 nsec at half-amplitude. So you need to talk to somebody about why you think a low propagation time will produce too many samples.

Also, you need desperately to talk to somebody about why you are unable to get a sample 997 to work. Until you do, you are dead in the water.

3)The choice between asynchronous and synchronous is pretty much irrelevant, although the problem of ripple-through delay needs to be addressed for an async counter. Since you don't seem to understand what this is, I'd recommend using a synchronous counter. You will need to provide data transfer to a holding register for transmission and a counter reset once per millisecond. Also, you'll need to address metastability issues during your transfer (what happens if you get a pulse while the transfer is occurring?)

4) Speed is not an issue. Assuming you use 2 bytes per packet (16 bits/packet) your data requirements are 16,000 bits/second, which is much lower than the 2 Mbit/sec you can get from Bluetooth. Of course, you're going to have to learn how to handle this stuff.

As you say, you have a lot to learn. I suggest you find somebody who has a clue and start picking his or her brains. That or read a LOT.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your encouragement. I will try my best to find someone who has a clue...although so far I could not find anyone.

Comment: @YoungwooCho - ask your professors about more senior students with experience. I'm not certain of your nationality, but at least in the US most people are flattered by requests to share expertise. Folks who have gone through the learning process may not be willing to provide a lot of detailed help, but if you ask they will probably be willing to point you at the books and other sources you need, which will cut down on the sense of helplessness which you may otherwise feel. You may also wind up making a few friends, too.

Comment: I found a paper that pretty much does exactly what I want to do: [link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268988318_The_ArduSiPM_a_compact_trasportable_SoftwareHardware_Data_Acquisition_system_for_SiPM_detector). But I am still having trouble using MAX997...I fried one by connecting the shutdown pin to GND, which the datasheet suggests. I don't want to repeat that mistake again, so I am quite hesitant to try something with the comparator

Comment: @YoungwooCho - Part of your problem is probably that the MAX997 doesn't have a shutdown pin.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the datasheet shows that MAX997 needs to be grounded in order to perform properly. Please take a look at pg 11 of the MAX997 datasheet

Comment: @YoungwooCho - Oops, looked at the wrong package. My apologies.  And you do need to ground the shutdown pin. See page 10. You were doing something else wrong.

Comment: by grounding do you mean I need to short the negative reference and the earth ground on the power supply? If so, is this a common practice when dealing with ICs?

Comment: @YoungwooCho - Tie it to pin 4. And yes, this is normal. The GND pin on the IC is generally connected to circuit ground, which may or may not be earth ground (but probably not in this case) Also, in your current edit, your R1 and R2 set the trigger point at 2.5 volts, which isn't going to work too well with a 100 mV input. Finally, there is no need whatsoever for your 1k on the output.

Comment: If I prototype this on a breadboard, does it matter if I have two separate wires going from ground rail to SHDN and GND? Also, is it okay to tie the function generator GND, oscilloscope GND, and power supply Common (NOT Earth GND) together?